# Is it possible to control the callerid output when calling a client rather than a number?

Tags: twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

Using Twilio when calling a phone number one has to put a valid phone number as the caller id.  However the documentation is sparse for the caller id when calling a mobile client.   [The Twml docs for callerid says:](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#callerid)

> If you are dialing a `<Client>`, you can also set a **valid client
> identifier as the callerId attribute**. For instance, if you’ve set up a
> client for incoming calls and you are dialing that client, you could
> set the callerId attribute to client:joey.

However, when I do this what the client sees in his caller id is the literal string 'client:joey'.  **What if I want the caller id to say 'joey' or 'Joey Joestar'?**

What constitutes a 'valid client identifer'?  Can I just set it to any string? or do I have to make a bunch of api calls or upfront settings changes to make that happen? (Is there any documentation on that system?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client identity does not allow special characters or spaces, and the **callerId**  has to be a valid client identity. Valid characters are **a-Z0-9** and **_**. You could use a unique hash for a user or for example map a [UUID and replace the hyphens with underscore](https://github.com/public-park/summer-camp/blob/master/src-server/helpers/twilio/TwilioHelper.ts).

You can add additional parameters to your **<Dial>** verb, these parameters are sent to the Client SDK and you can display them on an incoming call. In your example it would look like this if you call **Alice** and you want to display **Joe's name**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Client>
      <Identity>alice</Identity>
      <Parameter name="callerName" value="Joey Joestar"/>
    </Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications#dialclient